# saving csv for large dataframe is slow

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has 3 million rows and 67 columns. It takes about 7 minutes to write it out as csv.

```
final_df.to_csv("summary.csv.gz",index=False,compression="gzip")
```

I have tried increasing chunk size , didnt help much.

What can I do to make it write out the csv faster?
pandas version 0.24.2

Comment: Are any of your columns `datetime` dtype?

Comment: Yes one of the columns has date timestamp.

Comment: I would have thought this was a related to this issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25708. But given his 10M row 40 col DataFrame normally takes 12 minutes, I'd say your 3M row 67 column DataFrame writing time of 7 minutes is basically what you'd expect.